# Is photogrammetry and 3D scanning on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Photogrammetry (3D models from photos/videos) and 3D scanning (like structured light and ToF) are popular ways of obtaining a 3D model for printing.

Is the discussion of those techniques on-topic here?

Comment: 3D scanning should be on topic, it depends upon the question, I guess. See [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

3D scanning to generate 3D printable objects, and subsequently photogrammetry as one way to achieve 3D scans should be **On Topic**