# Is everything related to (or for the purpose of) 3D printing such as 3D scanning as well as 3D designing in-scope on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

In addition to this: [Is photogrammetry and 3D scanning on-topic?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/is-photogrammetry-and-3d-scanning-on-topic)

Shouldn't this site be called "3D manufacturing" or something broader? As 3D printing suggest only "printing" and not everything related to 3D printing such as 3D scanning or even 3D designing. I suppose that is off-topic? Is this scope defined somewhere?

Is everything related to (or for the purpose of) 3D printing such as 3D scanning using photogrammetry, NeRF or other techniques as well as 3D designing in-scope on this site?

I think both 3D scanning as well as 3D designing should be on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was  *originally* a 3D Printing site, and it still is.

However, then when certain questions were asked, that weren't about 3D printing (but which also didn't fit on any other site, i.e. Engineering), but were about similarly related topics (i.e. CNC, or cartesian laser etching machines), where (the particular aspects of) the technology that was asked about was *essentially* the same, it didn't make that much sense not to answer them, and so they became allowed, and so on - yes, there was (and sometimes still is) some *mission creep*.

All of this was covered by (amongst others) these three "umbrella" posts (in the following order):

1. [Game plan - What is on-topic?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/276/4762)
2. [On-topic has been updated - finally!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/413/4762)
3. [On-topic page is finally finished (again...)](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/504/4762)

So, the on-topic debate was finally (?) settled.

Yes, the on-topic subjects are maybe wider that the original "3D Printing site" concept. However, IMHO, changing the name at this late stage *might* be a bit drastic (possibly during beta stage is the latest opportunity for a name change?)... plus, the majority of the questions that hit the site are still *predominately* about 3D printing, as the first line of the on-topic page states:

> **Please make sure that your questions are intrinsically 3D printing oriented.**

3D scanning and 3D design *are* on-topic here, so long as the end result is (stated to be) a 3D printed model.

It should also be noted that 3D scanning *is* explicitly listed in the [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

If you would like to *suggest* a broader scoped "Manufacturing" site for Stack Exchange, then [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go. There was a [Digital Fabrication](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/digital-fabrication) site and a [Personal Manufacturing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246/personal-manufacturing) site but both of these apparently failed to get out of Beta. This site (with a narrower remit) took a *long* time to get out of Beta (see [What does it take to get out of Beta stage?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/264/4762)), and which was thankfully achieved, see [We're graduating!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/534/4762), due to the community successfully keeping the site centered around a 3D printing ethos.

Comment: That sounds great and then I saw this Stack site https://blender.stackexchange.com/. What an overlap. I really think that for those communities should merge to create one big "3D" site (manufacture or "print", scan, design). This site doesn't seem to have many active users IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 3D scanning and design.

### 3dprinting.stackexchange.com

- 14 results - https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=photogrammetry
- 0 results - https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=NeRF
- 251 results - https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=blender
- 19 results - https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=%223d+scan%22
- 279 results - https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=cad

### blender.stackexchange.com

- 151 results - https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=photogrammetry
- 2 results - https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=NeRF
- 500 results - https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=blender
- 79 results - https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%223d+scan%22
- 436 results - https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cad

What an overlap. I really think that for those communities should merge to create one big "3D" site (manufacture or "print", scan, design).